# When I push nextjs code to vercel with google analytics added by @next/third-parties it's showing the following error but it works in development mode

Tags: typescript, next.js, typescript-typings, google-analytics-4

> I have recently built a next.js project where I added Google Analytics from @next/third-parties/google. It's working fine in development mode but when I am deploying on vercel.com it's showing the following error.

````
     ` ./app/layout.tsx:34:24
      Type error: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable 
      to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      </NextAuthProvider>
   </body>
   <GoogleAnalytics gaId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS} />
                    ^
  </html>
);
}
  Error: Command "npx prisma generate && next build" exited with 
  1``your text```
````

Comment: How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at runtime, there is no TS type checking, so nothing will break except that `GoogleAnalytics` may not work if the `gaId` is undefined! If you don't have any type errors in your editor, it's possible that the editor isn't using the tsconfig configuration of the project.

But about the main issue, you can simply cast the type of `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS` to string, e.g:

```
<GoogleAnalytics gaId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS as string} />
```

Or just define the types of the environment variables in a type declaration file, e.g:

**src/env.d.ts:**

```js
namespace NodeJS {
  interface ProcessEnv {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS: string;
  }
}
```

By the way, consider validating environment variables. I suggest using [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod).

Comment: Thank you so much. It's a great help for me.